# why is my loop broken? 2d array of [20][6]

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here's what I have so far. I end up in and endless loop of entering the number for the array, however, it continues to cycle properly, as far as the numbers go

```
static void ticketNumberArray(){

    int number = 1;             //which of the six numbers you need from the ticket
    int ticketCount = 1;            //which ticket (out of 20) you are currently on

    while(ticketCount<21){      //sentinel controlled while loop, will continue until the twentieth ticket is entered

         System.out.println("Please type number " +number+ " of ticket number " +ticketCount+ ".");     //asks for the numbers of the ticket your currently on
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);             //initiates a scanner variable
         int ticketNumber = keyboard.nextInt();             //assigns user input to the double variable ticketNumber and initializes as a double

         tickets[ticketCount-1][number-1]=ticketNumber;     //assigns user input into a 2-d array

         number++;                                      //Sentinel variable

         if(number==7){                                     //loop that controls the ticket count, every 6 numbers ='s one ticket
          ticketCount++;
          number=1;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? I don't think your loop is "endless", it just takes a long time to terminate.

Comment: I'm trying to fill the 2d array with user generated numbers so I can compare the 2d array to a regular array and check to see if there are any matches, making the match a winner. It is definitely endless, I went through the cycle, 1 to 20, 5 times before I stopped.*edit* now it cycles twice then terminates...wth

Comment: `ticketCount` should eventually reach a value of `21` and terminate the loop since `number` will eventually reach a value of `7` and thus increment `ticketCount`. You may want to redesign your loop to use an inner loop.

Comment: I figured it out, I had added a method call to the end of the loop, and the class I started in took me to that mthod via another method call....so I called it onece, then ran through it again because i had the same method call at the end of the loop...the second method call was suppose to call my method to compare tickets for the winner. You were right, no endless loop, just not paying attention to methods I drop!

Comment: If that is the case, then the code you posted as part of your question is not complete and obviously does not demonstrate the issue you are having. In future, please be more vigilant about what you post if you expect us to determine why it isn't working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

This is something minor, but just for future reference, when you assign ticketNumber it's an int, but your comment says double. You probably mean int, but if you mix them up it could cause problems.

Comment: originally I was using a double, until I realized lottery numbers don't have decimals....<.<...I don't play the lottery btw

Comment: Okay. Just be careful when you switch variable type that you account for the switch everywhere you used the variable.

Comment: roger that, I usually am, I attack red squiggly lines as soon as I see them!

Answer (score 1):

It is not endless, it just need `20 * 6 = 120 times` for input user to end the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I can't see why it ends up into an endless loop. What I would do is trace the values of number and see if it doesn't jump the seven case. 
Also, as a good habit, I think it's better to change that equality (==) to a Superior or Equal (>=). You might end up changing the increment step in the future and forget to update the condition which will also end up in an endless loop :)
One last, non related remark, it is usually better to not use literal constant (like 7) and to prefer using declared constants. This is best for both code understanding and update.

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting your `ticketNumberArray()` method to the following:

```
static void ticketNumberArray()
{
   for (int ticketCount = 1; ticketCount <= 20; ticketCount++)
   {
      for (int numberCount = 1; numberCount <= 6; numberCount++)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter a number for ticket number " + ticketCount + ".");

         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         int number = keyboard.nextInt();

         tickets[ticketCount - 1][numberCount - 1] = number;
      }
   }
}
```

Your intent is more clear this way and it's more evident that your loops do in fact terminate.

Comment: Your second loop must equals to 7 not 6

Comment: The question title mentions an array with dimensions `[20][6]` and a comment in his code states "which of the six numbers you need from the ticket", so I assume he wants to use six numbers, not seven.

Comment: ah my bad, the `number++` is the first